# Update query returns false using pre-set values from form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I try to update my table with the `value=""` fields from my form the query fails and returns false, but I can't receive an error from it telling me what's wrong in any way.

```
$input = Input::get("textfield");
$option = Input::get("optionfield");

if($option == 0)
{
    $option = null;
}

if(empty($input))
{
    $input = null;
}

$update = MyTable::where("id", "=", 1)->update(["input" => $input, "option" => $option]);
```

If I change the value by typing something in the input field then it updates.

How come?

Comment: Why do you need update if values are null just skip the update and return in case of empty input values

Comment: Old values might not be null and if the field is empty it should be set to null

Comment: Seems you have problem due to `null` values. Have you tried `$option = ' ';` and `$nput=' ';` ? Are both fields are string ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically when we update existing data, we will compare new entries with the old ones. In your case, you have no comparison being done.

So, lets do that. I usually do this in my own cases:

- Fetch the existing data first

  ```
  $row = MyTable::where("id", 1)->first();
  ```
- Then, compare data

  ```
  $old_data = $row->toArray(); // convert to array first
  $new_data = Input::all(); // assuming all inputs are allowed for updates

  // now, lets compare values with additional index check
  $changes = array_diff_assoc($new_data, $old_data);

  // update row if has modifications
  if(!empty($changes)) {
      $row->update($changes);
  }
  ```

Hope this will help to solve your problem.